# How to prevent OS X from automatically deleting fonts after restarting?

Tags: macos, font, font-book

## Environment

- System version: 10.13.6 (17G65)
- Device: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2015)

## Actual Behavior

After system restart, certain fonts will disappear in Font Book.

All these fonts are "downloadable fonts" which occupy positions in the index in Font Book but do not actually exist on the device until the user downloads them.

Some "downloadable fonts" disappear but some remain. It is uncertain whether a certain removal pattern exists.

An incomplete list of fonts being affected:

- HeadLineA
- Hiragino Sans CNS
- LiHei Pro
- Wawati SC
- Wawati TC
- Weibei SC
- Weibei TC
- BiauKai

## Expected Behavior

These fonts remain intact after each system restart.

Comment: Do you really need them?  They are for Chinese/Japanese.

Comment: If I do not need them, I would not create this question.